# How can I import a file into pyscript and then analyze the file using pyscript?

Tags: javascript, python, html, pyscript

I'm attempting to create a web page that allows users to upload a CSV file, read it using Python through PyScript, and then print the content of the CSV file as a list. However, I'm encountering an error related to the 'document' object not being defined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css"/>
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
   <py-config>
      packages = ["pandas"]
    </py-config>
<div class="row overflow-hidden" id="content">
    <div class="col mh-100 float-left" id="main">
        <div id="fileinput"></div>
        <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload">
    </div>
</div>

        <py-script>
            import pandas as pd

            # Replace 'your_file.csv' with the path to your CSV file
            csv_file = document.getElementById('upload').files

            # Read the CSV file into a Pandas DataFrame
            df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

            # Convert each row to a list and store them in an array
            rows_array = df.values.tolist()

            # Now, 'rows_array' contains each row of the CSV file as a list
            print(rows_array)

        </py-script>

</body>
</html>
```

This was the error I recieved after trying to access the file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pyodide/pyscript/_internal.py", line 104, in run_pyscript
    result = eval_code(code, globals=__main__.__dict__)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lib/python311.zip/_pyodide/_base.py", line 468, in eval_code
    .run(globals, locals)
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/lib/python311.zip/_pyodide/_base.py", line 310, in run
    coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<exec>", line 4, in <module>
NameError: name 'document' is not defined
```

Comment: did you try to import the document like this : 
```from js import document```

Comment: This is what it gave me:
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'pyodide.ffi.JsProxy'>

Answer (score 2):

A couple things are happening here. First, your PyScript code is running immediately on page load, whereas you probably only want it to run when the user uploads a file. To do this, you can use the [`when` decorator](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/reference/API/when.html) or [`pyodide.ffi.addEventListener`](https://pyodide.org/en/0.23.2/usage/api/python-api/ffi.html#pyodide.ffi.wrappers.add_event_listener).

Next, the `files` attribute of an `<input>` retrieves an array of files. To get the singular first file, use `.item(0)`.

Finally, you cannot directly pass a [JS File Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) as a [Python file-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html). You'll need to extract the contents of the uploaded file and wrap them in a data structure like `io.BytesIO` that Python knows how to work with. Because retrieving the contents of a file in JS is a async operation, this makes our whole event handler async.

Here's a working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/releases/2023.05.1/pyscript.css"/>
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/releases/2023.05.1/pyscript.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
   <py-config>
      packages = ["pandas"]
    </py-config>
<div class="row overflow-hidden" id="content">
    <div class="col mh-100 float-left" id="main">
        <div id="fileinput"></div>
        <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload">
    </div>
</div>

<py-script>
    from js import document
    from io import BytesIO
    import pandas as pd

    from pyscript import when

    @when('change', '#upload')
    async def processFile(*args):
        csv_file = document.getElementById('upload').files.item(0)

        array_buf = await csv_file.arrayBuffer() # Get arrayBuffer from file
        file_bytes = array_buf.to_bytes() # convert to raw bytes array 
        csv_file = BytesIO(file_bytes) # Wrap in Python BytesIO file-like object

        # Read the CSV file into a Pandas DataFrame
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

        # Convert each row to a list and store them in an array
        rows_array = df.values.tolist()

        # Now, 'rows_array' contains each row of the CSV file as a list
        print(rows_array)
</py-script>

</body>
</html>
```